# Locked track Camera error

Tags: python, scripting, camera, constraints, tracking

Locked track object to camera x axis is very strange
When camera is on z axis(rotation) x axis of cube turn up
Is python can change it?

Comment: The question has very poor grammar, but it sounds like you were having trouble getting a tracking constraint to work properly. Python API should not be necessary to alter this, and I don’t think it’s possible. Try changing the constraint’s settings around a bit, or even try different tracking constraints (I think there are three versions).